# Mudar o estado pelo "current" ou pelo próprio valor do estado? Faz alguma diferença?

Tags: javascript, react, typescript, react-native

Aprendi a alterar dessas duas formas:

```
const [switch, setSwitch] = useState(false);

setSwitch(!switch);                         // 1
setSwitch(currentState => !currentState);   // 2
```

Há alguma diferença?
Sei que da 2ª forma ele retorna o estado exato mais "fiel" do que da 1ª forma. Há algum problema em usar da 1ª forma?

Comment: Não sei o porque do negativo, porque realmente existe diferença! aqui eu parei de responder alguns questionamento por causa disso, a falta de conhecimento alinhado com os votos negativos ...!

Comment: E qual é a diferença?

Comment: @BernardoLansing: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fiddle-forked-f6r4vr?file=/src/App.js dá uma olhada nesse código e verifique que há diferença de como você faz, falta algum contexto na pergunta talvez, mas, é real que existe diferença! e isso impacta em muito no desenvolvimento, tem dois botões eles se comportam diferente na atualização da variavel number

Comment: @novic, me surgiu uma dúvida relacionada https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fiddle-forked-3ugn0t , se for passado um [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) o comportamento é mesmo que `setNumber(number + 1);` no sandbox e `setSwitch(!switch);` na pergunta.

Comment: A pergunta é boa, no [SOEn há uma pergunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48003153/11379709) onde o ponto de discórdia entre todas as respostas e comentários é justamente o que está sendo levantado aqui.

Comment: @AugustoVasques sim, é engraçado esse comportamente porque eu sinceramente é a primeira vez que eu vi esse tipo de expressão em conjunto (não sei se é expressão). mas, de certa forma parece que está sendo passado a ultimo valor e ai recai no que você mesmo relatou que o comportamento é o mesmo que o `valor + 1`. Vale salientar que existem momentos que precisa se alterado na mesma função o valor varias vezes de algum estado e isso com a solução que eu passei fica próximo a vida real. (comportamento)

Answer (score 0):

Sim, faz diferença.

O primeiro setSwitch(!switch) é usado para inverter o valor atual do switch e atualizar o estado do componente. Isso é feito através do operador de negação (!), que inverte o valor de switch.

O segundo setSwitch(currentState => !currentState) também é usado para inverter o valor atual do switch, mas ele faz isso usando uma função que recebe o estado atual como parâmetro e retorna o novo valor para o estado. Isso é útil quando você precisa basear o novo valor do estado em seu valor atual, mas também pode ser usado como um meio de garantir que o componente só atualize o estado com o valor correto.

Em resumo, ambos os setSwitch são usados para inverter o valor do switch, mas o segundo faz isso de forma mais controlada e segura, pois garante que o novo valor do estado é baseado no valor atual e não em qualquer outra fonte.